# How to run multiple Blazor WASM in single website?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I would like to create one website where some sub-functionalities will be split into multiple Blazor projects.

So the main site is one Blazor App, but /private and /shop are separate Blazor apps, where users need to register and login to access functionality. As the main site should have a navbar that is common for all sites (login and register buttons are there), how can you communicate between Blazor apps?

Comment: Why must it be separate apps, you can make a blazor side where login is only required for some parts of the side.

Comment: See this article I wrote a while ago - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5287009/Blazor-Hydra-Hosting-Multiple-Blazor-SPAs-on-a-sin